# I am looking for a list of characters to make ascii art

Tags: python, ascii

I coded a program to make ascii art and for the characters I have the following string: """.:-=+*#%@&"""

But it's a pretty short one and I can't find one that's longer to make images a little more detailed than that
Does anyone have this? (preferably put in order (like the one I already have))

Comment: What's to prevent you from adding additional characters in your preferred order to the list you already have?

Answer (score 1):

string = ' !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïð[\]^_`{|}~'

You can also use [this](https://theasciicode.com.ar/) website to get each ASCII code individually.

Answer (score 0):

In python you can access all ascii characters like this:

```
>>> import string
>>> string.printable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use chr() to get the corresponding character.

For example this:

```
"".join([chr(i) for i in range(32, 1032)])
```

gives you the first 1000 characters.

Answer (score 0):

**Figlet and Ascii art letters**

[Figlet](http://www.figlet.org/) has been a long running way to generate words and sentences in Ascii art. [pifiglet](https://pypi.org/project/pyfiglet/0.7/) is a full Figlet port into python.

**Font Selection**

When choosing fonts be sure to use "monospace" fonts: where all letters print in the same with, like <code%Sgt; puts out. Traditional "proportional" fonts, like on plain text, will make pictures look funny.

Courier fonts are tend to be monospace fonts that are universally available across all platforms. Other fonts with "monospace" in their names can work, but may not be as universally available across platforms or operating systems.

**Monospace Font Example**

```
8""8""8                                               
8  8  8 eeeee eeeee eeeee eeeee eeeee eeeee eeee eeee 
8e 8  8 8  88 8   8 8  88 8   " 8   8 8   8 8  8 8    
88 8  8 8   8 8e  8 8   8 8eeee 8eee8 8eee8 8e   8eee 
88 8  8 8   8 88  8 8   8    88 88    88  8 88   88   
88 8  8 8eee8 88  8 8eee8 8ee88 88    88  8 88e8 88ee
```

**Proportional Font Example**

Can also pick up corruptions from "markdown" doing odd things with some special characters when used outside of preformatted or code blocks.

8""8""8

8  8  8 eeeee eeeee eeeee eeeee eeeee eeeee eeee eeee

8e 8  8 8  88 8   8 8  88 8   " 8   8 8   8 8  8 8

88 8  8 8   8 8e  8 8   8 8eeee 8eee8 8eee8 8e   8eee

88 8  8 8   8 88  8 8   8    88 88    88  8 88   88

88 8  8 8eee8 88  8 8eee8 8ee88 88    88  8 88e8 88ee

**Fonts and Drawings**
As far as letters go the way different fonts display the same letter means you can't fine tune how your artwork displays. In the long gone days of line printers we could overprint to enrich the characters, but that is more difficult now.